# Push local Git branch to origin

Tags: git

I'm working on two machines and origin repo on third one (origin is accessible from the other two, no direct connection between machine1 and machine2).

```
# Machine 1
$ git branch
  master
* testing
  cms

# Machine 2
$ git branch
* master
```

Now, I want to push the `testing` branch to the origin and have it on machine2 too, so the final effect would be:

```
# Machine 2
$ git branch
* testing
  master
```

I have tried:

```
# Machine 1
$ git push origin testing

# Machine 2
$ git pull origin testing                # bunch of merge conflicts
$ git checkout -b testing origin/testing # errors too
```

Current state is:

```
# Machine 1
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/testing
```

How to do it?

My next question probably will be: how to delete the `origin/testing` branch?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is missing information on what kind of errors that you were getting when trying to `git checkout -b testing origin/testing`. Also, you don't explain if you want to delete the `testing` branch on the remote repo, or if you just want to delete the remote-tracking branch `origin/testing` locally.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have successfully pushed the testing branch to origin so now you just need to get the branch to machine2.

Not sure of the state of teh repo on machine2 so I would delete the directory (Or create a new one to use) and just clone the repo on Machine2 and checkout testing ...

So on Machine2 in an empty dir (new or clean):

```
$ git clone git@github/somewhere
$ git branch
* master

$ git checkout testing
# ...
# something about getting and switching
# ... 

$ git branch
* testing 
master
```

Answer (score 24):

Instead of using `git pull` (which fetches and merges), try `git fetch` (which won't try to merge with your current branch on machine2, and cause conflicts):

```
# Machine 1
$ git push origin testing

# Machine 2
$ git fetch origin testing
$ git checkout -b testing origin/testing
```

Answer (score 1):

The original poster states:

> My next question probably will be: how to delete the `origin/testing` branch?

You have to be clear what you mean by that, because after you push `testing` to the remote repo, there will also be a ***local*** remote-tracking branch called `origin/testing` that keeps track of the last known status of the `testing` branch on the remote. You can find this remote-tracking branch under `.git/refs/remotes/origin/`.

### Deleting both the remote `testing` and local `origin/testing` branches

If you delete the branch on the remote with the following commands:

```bash
git push origin :testing
# Or
git push origin --delete testing
```

then the *local* remote-tracking branch `origin/testing` will also be deleted for you automatically.

### Deleting just the local `origin/testing` branch

If for some reason you just wanted to delete the local remote-tracking branch `origin/testing`, but not the `testing` branch on the remote, then you can run the `git branch -d` command with the `--remotes` or `-r` flag:

```bash
git branch --delete --remotes origin/testing
# Or shorter
git branch -dr origin/testing
```

If you get an error message that the branch can't be deleted because it hasn't been merged yet, then you can force the deletion by using the `-D` flag instead of `--delete` or `-d`.

### See Also

- [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/23961231#23961231)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is the following:

*On Machine 1*, deploy the remote branch and link the local testing branch to it:

```
git push -u origin testing
```

*On Machine 2*, deploy a local branch that's linked to the remote testing branch:

```
git fetch origin && git checkout --track origin/testing
```

Now both local testing branches must be deployed and linked to the remote testing branch =)

Now for deleting a remote branch you can simply try this :

```
git push origin --delete testing
```

or

```
git push origin :testing
```